# OpenLDAP TLS negotiation failure ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11) additional info: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: ssl, openssl, ldap, tls, openldap

I  have tried to configure Openldap with TLS. I have an TLS certificates and configured with .ldif file and changed necessary configuration in ldap.conf file. I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS operating system.

Checking the LDAP with following commands

```
 # ldapsearch -x 
 able to see the DIT as follows 
 # search result
 search: 2
 result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 28
# numEntries: 27
```

while accessing with TLS support option that is

## ldapsearch -x -ZZ

getting the following error 
  ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
        additional info: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

In /var/log/syslog

```
May 25 12:47:46 ip-172-30-0-218 slapd[6560]: conn=1005 fd=19 ACCEPT from IP=127.                                                                                        0.0.1:54306 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
May 25 12:47:46 ip-172-30-0-218 slapd[6560]: conn=1005 op=0 EXT oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.                                                                                        1466.20037
May 25 12:47:46 ip-172-30-0-218 slapd[6560]: conn=1005 op=0 STARTTLS
May 25 12:47:46 ip-172-30-0-218 slapd[6560]: conn=1005 op=0 RESULT oid= err=0 te                                                                                        xt=
May 25 12:47:46 ip-172-30-0-218 slapd[6560]: conn=1005 fd=19 closed **(TLS negotia                                                                                        tion failure)**
```

Here is the configurations of ldap.conf

```
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=infoarmor,dc=com

URI     ldap://  ldapi:// ldaps://
#URI     ldap://192.168.1.123:389
#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

SSL     start_tls

TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/_wildcard.infoarmor.com.crt

 TLS_REQCERT     demand
```

## Here is the configurations of ssl.ldif

```
dn: cn=config
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/ldap.test.com.crt

replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/ldap.test.com.crt

repalce: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ldap/ssl/ldap.test.com.key

replace: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH:+SSLv3:+TLSv1:MEDIUM:+SSLv2:@STRENGTH:+SHA:+MD5:!NULL

replace: olcSecurity
olcSecurity: tls=1
```

Please help me if you have any idea